# jQuery - dropdown ajax show/hide

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have this problem ... I want to make the show hide some dropdowns with ajax, I don't know where to place the show hide code ... it only shows the first country, after selecting the country will appear and choose the city state to appear. ... can you help me fix this code?
this is my code and script

```html
<div class="frmDronpDown">
        <div class="row">
          <label>Country:</label><br/>
          <select name="country" id="country-list" class="demoInputBox" onChange="getState(this.value);">
<option value disabled selected>Select Country</option>
<?php
foreach($results as $country) {
?>
<option value="<?php echo $country["id"]; ?>"><?php echo $country["country_name"]; ?></option>
<?php
}
?>
</select>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <label>State:</label><br/>
          <select name="state" id="state-list" class="demoInputBox" onChange="getCity(this.value);">
<option value="">Select State</option>
</select>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <label>City:</label><br/>
          <select name="city" id="city-list" class="demoInputBox">
<option value="">Select City</option>
</select>
        </div>
      </div>
```

```js
 function
        getState(val) {
          $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "getState.php",
            data: 'country_id=' + val,
            success: function(data) {
              $("#state-list").html(data);
              getCity();
            }
          });
        }


        function
        getCity(val) {
          $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "getCity.php",
            data: 'state_id=' + val,
            success: function(data) {
              $("#city-list").html(data);
            }
          });
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.prop` for that. You can refer [here.](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)

You must start your script with `$(document).ready(function())` so that JS will know if the page is loaded and ready.

Then consider this logic here. (Example code)

```
if($("#country-list option:selected").index() == 0){

                $("#state-list").prop("hidden", true);

                }else{

                $("#state-list").prop("hidden", false);
            }
```

The code above actually checks if the country-list items is not selected when the page loaded, the other dropdown will consider it as hidden, or else it is shown.

Comment: i use code from here, but i dont know just to add show hide function  https://phppot.com/php/country-state-city-example-cascading-jquery-dependent-dropdown/

Answer (score 0):

Add a hidden class to state and city drop-downs in HTML to hide them from initial state.
Display the state drop-down when country is selected.

If 'Select' option is selected/ value is cleared, then add the hidden class to the cascading drop-downs

```js
var 
stateContainer = $('.state-container'),
cityContainer = $('.city-container'),
countryList = $('#country-list'),
stateList = $('#state-list'),
cityList = $('#city-list');

countryList.on('change', function() {

  if (this.value === '') {
    stateContainer.addClass('hidden');
    cityContainer.addClass('hidden');
    stateList.val('');
    cityList.val('');
  } else {

    stateContainer.removeClass('hidden');
    //getState(this.value);
  }
});

stateList.on('change', function() {
  if (this.value === '') {
    cityContainer.addClass('hidden');
    cityList.val('');
  } else {

    cityContainer.removeClass('hidden');
    //getCity(this.value);
  }

});
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="frmDronpDown">
  <div class="row">
    <label>Country:</label><br/>
    <select name="country" id="country-list" class="demoInputBox" >
      <option value="" selected>Select Country</option>
      <option value="A">Country A</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <div class="row state-container hidden">
    <label>State:</label><br/>
    <select name="state" id="state-list" class="demoInputBox" >
      <option value="">Select State</option>
      <option value="A">State A</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <div class="row city-container hidden">
    <label>City:</label><br/>
    <select name="city" id="city-list" class="demoInputBox">
      <option value="">Select City</option>
      <option value="A">City A</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks, it can hide now, but my program fail to unhide/ show, i use mysql database

Comment: tis is my code https://drive.google.com/file/d/1B4yiGzpjTeLni_MHXmPNWgkKWLjhIjry/view?usp=sharing can you help me to fix it?

Comment: check if your ajax is working fine or not. I don't think there is any issue with the html and script part..

Comment: the ajax working fine, but it just cant show after i choose country, dont know wheres the wrong

Comment: looking at your ajax call, you are calling getCity() without sending any parameters to it. That's inside getState() method; comment out that line

Comment: function 
getState(val) {
 $.ajax({
 type: "POST",
 url: "getState.php",
 data:'country_id='+val,
 success: function(data){
  $("#state-list").html(data);
  getCity();
 }
 });
}


function 
getCity(val) {
 $.ajax({
 type: "POST",
 url: "getCity.php",
 data:'state_id='+val,
 success: function(data){
  $("#city-list").html(data);
 }
 });
}

Comment: i use that for ajax

Comment: you do not need getCity() in getState method. remove it